# read_chunk doesn't work

Tags: knitr, rnw

I tried the code suggested previously which should work

[execute R code in latex file imported from separate R file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419510/execute-r-code-in-latex-file-imported-from-separate-r-file?newreg=30e3c98007a8417c9a95b791e1b00e03)

but I can't see the external-code from R.

Here's my script

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{Sweave} 

\title{Summary}

<<echo=FALSE, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
@

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

\maketitle

\begin{enumerate}
\item sentence1
\item sentence2
\end{enumerate}

<<external-code,cache=F,echo=F,include=T>>= % echo decides whether to include r source code in output file
knitr::read_chunk("test.R")
@

<<external-code,echo=F>>=
@

\end{document}
```

---

where my test.R is as follow:

```
# ---- external-code ----
cat('and I am R and 1+1 is ', 1+1)
runif(100,1,2)
```

Pdf output from rnw.file only printed my text, but no R output. Both files are located in the same file Can't quite figure out whats wrong.

Comment: How did you compile the Rnw document? If you are using RStudio, make sure you are using knitr instead of Sweave to compile Rnw: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27592837/559676

Comment: Yes. figured out that problem, was using Sweave! Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved in comment (trivial error).